# How can I implement a cooldown on enderpearls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a private pvp server with my friends, and I am the only one that sort of knows how to program things, and I would like to know how to make enderpearl cooldowns, so you can only throw an enderpearl every 10s.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post...

Answer (score 1):

1) Enderpearl cooldown is a vanilla feature in 1.9. You cannot affect the time it takes for them to recharge though.

2) To rename items without them being italicized, you need to download a third-party application such as NBT explorer, and edit the data of the item with it. There are plenty of online guides to do this. Be warned, you will be using this symbol a lot! §